# Having problems from exiting a simple while loop

Tags: c++

So I am trying to write a program that gets value from user and is supposed to stop  after the user types in q but for some reason this program is not working, even after I test with q or Q the program does not stop running.

```
vector <string> names;
vector <int> ticPurch; 

int numOfRaff; 
string nameOfpart; 

   cout << "Enter the name of the participant, enter q to quit " << endl; 
   cin >> nameOfpart; 

while(nameOfpart != "q" || nameOfpart != "Q"){

    names.push_back(nameOfpart);
    cout << "Please enter the number of tickets the participant bought " << endl; //Getting input and storing them in vector
    cin >> numOfRaff; 
    ticPurch.push_back(numOfRaff);
    cout << endl; 
    cout << "Enter the name of the participant, enter q to quit " << endl; 
    cin >> nameOfpart;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `&&` instead of `||`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an or statement `||`. Of course the string will be not-equal to one or not-equal to the other.

You need to use and `&&`. If it is not 'q' AND it is not 'Q' then loop.

You should also check that `cin` is valid. Your whole `if` statement could be:

```
while(cin && nameOfpart != "q" && nameOfpart != "Q") {
```

Comment: ah ok I thought or statements only cared if one part was true and it did not look for the other part

Answer (score 2):

If you enter "q", then "q" != "Q" is true, then it continues, and viceversa.
You should use instead

```
while(nameOfpart != "q" && nameOfpart != "Q")
```

Comment: ah but when doing or, doesnt it only look for one statement to be true and not both?

Comment: Yes it does look for only one statement, thats why you got it true everytime

Comment: Hey, so if the user types in q then shouldn't the compiler just look at the first one, and q =! q is false so shouldn't the loop stop if I did have || cause || only checks the first statement?

Comment: When you use an or, the moment a condition is true it doesn't  matter the value of the other conditions

Comment: hm but why q != q is false right, so shouldn't the loop stop right there?

Comment: If thats the only condition yes, the loop will stop. If there is another condition, like q != Q will be true then with the or it will continue.

Comment: oh so || still looks at the other condition?

Comment: Exactly, till it finds one to be true, and returns false only if all are false